# summarize mutlitple values sent to graphite at the same time

Tags: sum, aggregation, graphite

I'm trying to display the sum of several values ​​sent to Graphite (carbon-cache) for the same timestamp.

Sent values are like :

```
test.nb 10 1421751600
test.nb 11 1421751600
test.nb 12 1421751600
test.nb 13 1421751600
```

and I would Graphite to display value "46" for timestamp 1421751600.

Only the last value "13" is displayed on Graphite.

Here are configuration files :

storage-aggregation.conf

```
[test_sum]
pattern = ^test\.*
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = sum
```

storage-schemas.conf

```
[TEST]
pattern = ^test\.
retentions = 10s:30d
```

Is there a way to do this with Graphite/Carbon ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

**storage-aggregation.conf** file defines how to aggregate data to lower precision retentions and since you only have one retention precision defined: 10s for 30 days, this is not needed.

In order to this with Graphite daemons, you will have to use 
carbon-aggregator.py that is run in front of carbon-cache.py to buffer metrics over time. Check [aggregator] section in config file. By default, **carbon-aggregator** listens on port 2023 (default) so you will have to send data points to this port and not carbon-cache port (2004 by default).

Also, you will have to specify the aggregation rule in **aggregation-rules.conf** that will allow you to add several metrics together as the come in. You can find detailed explanation [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf).